# Holomorphic vector fields on complex projective spaces

Tags: complex-geometry

Question: is there a simple description of holomorphic vector fields on the complex projective space $\mathbb{C P}^n$ ?

More precisely : for $n=1$, the holomorphic vector fields are of the form $P(z) \frac{d}{dz}$ in coordinates, where $P$ is a polynomial of degree less than 2. Is there a similar description in terms of homogeneous coordinates for $n >1$ ?

Answer (score 6):

You can describe them using the [Euler sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_sequence). It turns out that they are the classes of homogeneous linear polynomial vector fields on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$
$$ \sum A_i(z_0, \dots , z_n)\frac{\partial}{\partial z_i} $$
($A_i$ homogeneous polynomial of degree one) modulo
$$R = \sum z_i \frac{\partial}{\partial z_i}  $$
the radial vector field.

Take a look at Huybrechts' book Complex Geometry, an introduction.